# jQuery selectors: only link with images inside them

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, colorbox

I want to open images with some kind of lightbox, colorbox for an example. How would it be possible to open only link which have images inside them and are in .content class?

Something like:

```
$('.content a img').colorbox();
```

Comment: While they are a superset of CSS selectors, what you are looking for is not a CSS selector but a jQuery selector - CSS itself does not support a way to select an elemend based on what children it contains.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Although you technically *are* right, I just want to point out that there's already a spec for this sort of thing. The selector would be as follows: `.content $a img`. Needless to say, no browser out there supports this yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
$('.content a:has(img)').colorbox();
```

---

In case you already have a jQuery object `$('.content a')` containing all links you could also call `.has('img')` on it to reduce its elements just like the selector would do.

Comment: Thank you, I will mark it as the answer later, can't do it so quick.

Comment: I almost posted `$('.content a img').each(function(){$(this.parent('a').colorbox();) });` But I knew there had to be a better way

Comment: `$('.content a img').closest('a')` might do the job, too - but yeah, not really a good solution.

Comment: It's actually pretty much [the same thing as `has`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.has).