# How can I use the CSS before selector for links except those containing an <img>

Tags: css, pseudo-class

```
a:before {
    content: "› ";
}

a img:before {
    content: ""
}
```

I know the above syntax is incorrect technically and semantically, but I want to exclude the content from the a tag any time an img is included within. Is this possible, or should I do it with a class instead, i.e.

```
a:before {
    content: "> ";
}

a.no-before:before {
    content: "";
}
```

I'd prefer to do it without having to define classes for it, but I can see that might be required.

I'd like to do this with only CSS, no JS involvement.

Comment: If you want to hide content of anchor tag if it contains image then you can use JS or if the image is of fixed height and width you can set a class with following properties: `overflow:hidden; max-width:img's width; max-height:img's height;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the CSS psuedo-selectors didn't seem up to the task, I went the route of having a class which excluded the `:before` content where I didn't want it:

```
a:before {
    content: "› "
}

a.no-before-content:before {
    content: ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe ur trying to achieve somthing as in this thread,pls check out.                                    [jQuery selectors: only link with images inside them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917050/jquery-selectors-only-link-with-images-inside-them)

Comment: I'd like to do it with just CSS3, not any javascript involvement. Looks like the cleanest solution at the moment is just to use a class when I don't want the `:before` content to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant do this using CSS3 , there is no `has()`,no `contains()` and no `parent()`,they exists only in jQuery selectors.